# What is the benefit from knowing the operator precedence in performance?

Tags: performance, operator-precedence

We all know the precedence of operators. So, after knowing that, what can we do with it?
I am thinking 2  + (3/5 * 26) is slower than 3/5 * 6 + 2. I say that because I implemented my Shunting Yard algorithm, and the first case would result in pushing 2 + in the stsack until, the parenthesis is done, but in 2nd case 3/5 would immediatedly be evaluated. What else can be done faster with keeping precedence in mind? Or does it not matter?

Comment: Don't try to solve questions of performance by thinking about them, set up some tests and make some measurements.  Be careful in both of those aspects of investigation.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Yes sir